# Do we really need a hydrogen tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I know that element specific tags have been discussed before.
The consensus seemed to be that they are unnecessary and I agree with that.
However, I wonder if hydrogen might be an exception.
It's ubiquitous nature and the fact that it has it's own unique bond make me
think yes but I cant articulate this well enough for a satisfactory tag wiki entry.  Thoughts?

There is both a 'tagging' tag and a 'tags' tag here.  Perhaps we need a meta meta.

Comment: We can discuss the meta on meta itself. I've merged the two tags; thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: @ManishEarth Are you sure they mean the same thing? Isn't "tags" supposed to deal with questions regarding usage of tags, and "tagging" supposed to deal with how to tag questions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meh, if the tag is flourishing I see no reason to remove it. BUT, I'd prefer to detag all the posts that use [hydrogen](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hydrogen) just because they contain Hydrogen somewhere in the post.

About the tag wiki: Generally you fill it with:

- A bit more info about the tag
- Relevant links for the tag (tutorials, etc if applicable)

It's fine if the tag doesn't have a wiki. If you want to add one, please don't copy it from somewhere else, write it in your own words.

Comment: This is the right approach. If the question's focus isn't predominantly *about* hydrogen, it shouldn't be tagged as such.

Comment: @RobertCartaino: Yep :) I'll slowly detag the errant posts so that nobody notices.